Theorem 30.2 of Munkres' book on Topology
I'm not too sure whether I understand the proof of the following theorem from James Munkres' book on Topology:
Theorem 30.2 A subspace of a second-countable space is second-countable, and a countable product of second-countable spaces is second-countable.
Proof. Consider the second countability axiom. If $\mathscr{B}$ is a countable basis for $X$, then $\{B\cap A\mid B\in\mathscr{B}\}$ is a countable basis for the subspace $A$ of $X$. If $\mathscr{B}_i$ is a countable basis for the space $X_i$, then the collection of all product $\prod U_i$, where $U_i$ in $\mathscr{B}_i$ for finitely many values of $i$ and $U_i=X_i$ for all other values of $i$, is a countable basis for $\prod X_i$.
I'm not necessarily convinced why this proves the second statement, why do we take finitely many of the $U_i$'s to be in $\mathscr{B}_i$ and the others to be $X_i$'s? Like say, how would this work if $\prod X_i$ were to be equal to $X\times Y$ for some space Y? Do we take both $U_i$'s to be in the $\mathscr{B}_i$'s or do we take one to be in there and the other to be $X$ or $Y$?
I did see this related post: Prove that the following set is countable., but it didn't quite answer my question.

If it is $X \times Y$ (or more generally the product of finitely many $X_i$), then you can choose all $U_i$ to be in $\mathscr{B}_i$. After all, that is “finitely many” $U_i$ in $\mathscr{B}_i$.

@DavidGao Ah I see, so as long as we have a finite product, we just take them all to be in the $\mathscr{B}_i$'s, but when it become a "strict" countable product, we have to choose some to be equal to the $X_i$'s?

Basically, yeah. I think Authur’s answer also already clarified this.

@DavidGao Yea I read it just after I read your comment and posted mine, thanks!

For finite products, like $X\times Y$, which in light of the proof is more aptly named $X_1\times X_2$, we have that $\{U_1\times U_2\mid U_1\in\mathscr B_1, U_2\in\mathscr B_2\}$ is a basis for the product topology, and it is countable. Only finitely many of the $U_i$ (which is to say, at most two of them) lie in $\mathscr B_i$, and for the rest of them (which is to say, none in most cases, but also possibly one or two) of the $U_i$s are equal to $X_i$. That's not really the important case, however.
The important case is when you have countably infinite many $X_i$. In this case, the standard basis for the product topology on $\prod X_i$ is
$$
\left\{\prod U_i \mid U_i\subseteq X_i\text{ open}, \text{only finitely many }U_i\neq X_i\right\}
$$
It is a standard exercise to see that if you restrict yourself from using any open $U_i\subseteq X_i$ to using $U_i\in\mathscr B_i$, you get a (potentially) smaller basis, but the same topology (this holds no matter what basis the different $\mathscr B_i$ are, we do not need any second countability for this particular part of the argument). That is the basis they are using here.
There is also a need to prove that this basis is actually countable, but apparently Munkres has left that as implicitly known. Your linked question addresses that particular part of the proof.
